# iOS crash - Selector name found in current argument registers: retain

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

In hockey app dashboard, I'm getting crashes with following hints:

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x1943f61e8
Crashed Thread:  7
Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: retain

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x568855a90
Crashed Thread:  18
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: retain

Both crash groups are hitting same code but somehow they had different crash description which I believe should be same root cause.

This is what my code looks like:

thread 1:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
@synchronized (self) {
    queue = _mySerialQueue;
}
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ // Crash happens here
    if (_ivar) {
        ...
    }
});
```

thread 2:

```
@synchronized (self) {
    _mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create(...);
}
```

Can this code run into ARC issue?

Comment: Are you guaranteeing that code on thread 1 is executed after the code on thread 2?

Comment: Is the crash random? (where random means it happens once in a while, but not reproducibly?)

Comment: @bbum: if not, `_mySerialQueue` would be `nil`, and `[nil retain]` never crashes

Comment: @Michael Yeah;  but dispatch_async(nil, ...) is undefined IIRC and, given blocks runtime, there might be a path that'd lead to [garbage retain].

Comment: @bbum: no there isn't. I looked at the assembly :) It just crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS because it tries to dereference a NULL pointer. The pointers in this question however: 0x1943f61e8 points to some iVar and 0x568855a90 points at an object (all objects are 16-byte-aligned and the first pointer is not 16-byte-aligned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the premise that (please verify these)

- `_mySerialQueue` is an instance variable
- `_mySerialQueue` is only accessed within `@synchronized(self)` blocks
- You don't access `_mySerialQueue` via any property or via key value coding (`[theObject valueForKey:"mySerialQueue"]`)
- All code you posted runs with ARC

I see only one reason why the above code could crash the way it does. I'm still not 100% sure about that, but here is my shot:

`self` is in the process of being deallocated when the crash happens. It can be checked if you clean the iVar in `dealloc`:

```c
- (void)dealloc {
    @synchronized(self) {
        _mySerialQueue = nil;
    }

    // ...
}
```

these crashes would be extremely rare, e.g. one in a hundred at least. If it happens more often, I think the problem is somewhere else.

After the change, the app would still crash, but the EXC_BAD_ACCESS would be at a lower memory location because you are dereferencing a NULL pointer when you call `dispatch_async(nil, ...)`. The crash location will most likely be 0x00000050, or a similarily low address.

**Why do I think this?**
When an object is being destructed, the iVars are destroyed in a separate pass by a method named `.cxx_destruct`. When this happens, the iVar can be in the process of being deallocated, but at the same time the variable still points to the object because it is never cleared.

**Important:** If this works, it will just replace one rare crash with another rare crash, because it would mean that there is a race condition on `self` somewhere.

---

Another possible solution would be to try to reproduce the problem with the *thread sanitizer*. It can track down such problems pretty fast in most cases.

Comment: This is a reasonable conjecture.   In particular, if `self` represents some kind of worker object, something needs to maintain a strong reference to `self` until the unit(s) of work are done.   Failure to do so is a *really* common cause of crashes in concurrent models.

Comment: The premises you brought up are met in my code.
And you are right, the crash is not easily reproducible. It happened like <1% and I have never been able to reproduce locally. 

What you suggest is definitely making sense to me! Thanks.

But I want to verify the change without going through the whole release cycle, do you have any idea how can I reproduce the issue maybe in a hacky way? So that I can verify the difference before and after the fix :)

Comment: @JayceeJiang: I think you could try the "thread sanitizer". (You'll find many resources if you google for "ios thread sanitizer"). If you play around with your app for a few minutes it will probably find the issue. If this doesn't help, I would try the "undefined behaviour sanitizer" next. And if that doesn't help you may run the clang analyzer (Xcode menu -> Product -> Analyze).

Comment: @JayceeJiang: also note, that if you haven't run the thread sanitizer yet, it may find plenty of other issues first. It may take a few hours to fix all of that.. (I've been there.)